Logic Apps Blob File Content Size changing when Posting to API
I have a Logic App which will periodically list contents of Blob Storage and post any files found to an API, and I thought it was working - at least on some file types.   But currently it's finding PGP encrypted files (ie: myfile.txt.pgp) and I'm finding that the file is not posting properly to my API.  The file size (byte[] length) is almost double upon arrival at the API.

The body of my post: `
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "body": "@{body('Get_blob_content_(V2)')}",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=original;  filename=@{item()?['Name']}",
        "Content-Type": "@{item()?['MediaType']}"
      }
    },
    {
      "body": "@{item()?['Path']}",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=fullname;"
      }
    },
    {
      "body": "@{item()?['Size']}",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=blobsize;"
      }
    }
  ]
}

`
In the above content flow, the content length for the blob is 4078, and posted "blobSize" reflects this (4078).   But in the API - the posted file is something like 7479 in size (and is not formatted properly, I cannot decrypt the PGP).
The API works flawlessly uploading the same file and other form parameters (using standard Postman or my UI).   But when the API is called from logic apps to send the blob "File Content", it is somehow sent in a different format, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly parse it.
EDIT: When uploading text files (not PGP encrypted), I can see that the "File Content" is actually returning the string content of the file. So it appears that it is actually doing this to the PGP file as well, but the string content is encrypted and useless.  How do I get and send the raw file binary instead of the string contents?
Following is the resulting body of the HTTP call (content truncated) - I've noticed that when this is a text file, the content is actually the string contents of the file.   The below is the content when trying a non-text file (in this case pgp):
{
"$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
"$multipart": [
    {
        "body": "�\u0001\f\u0003��h\b*D5...  [truncated]",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=original;  filename=ADVW4421_20241102_005627.txt.pgp",
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
        }
    },
    {
        "body": "/acgi/woodmen/ADVW4421_20241102_005627.txt.pgp",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=fullname;"
        }
    },
    {
        "body": "4087",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=blobsize;"
        }
    }
]

}

I believe that this issue would be the same for images, zip files, or other non-text files.  I don't really that I don't want the "content" of files (ie text), but I want to simply get the file itself - either in stream or byte[].   Is there a way to get the binary data of a blob instead of the text content?

Show us an example of the output, even a truncated example would be fine, a screenshot even.

Added contents above

Convert it to base64 and send it that way and the convert it back to a byte array on your server side.

When you get the content (via get blob content action) it is base64 encrypted. You can convert it to binary using function base64tobinary(<pass your base 64 content here>)
use it in a compose action and pass the output as usual.

Laviza I have also tried this, with the same result...  The size is slightly different when hitting the API, but it's still about 175%...
